# applying auto local storage using vanilla javascript to these input field ids

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to use local storage on a Sharepoint page that leverages just basic javascript. I have these input fields that I WANT to auto save the data per each field. There is no button for me to save. how can this be done?

```js
// Store data
var someData = document.getElementById("photoLink_9795a9ff-f5c2-49b6-bc72-13240caf7a7b_$UrlControlId").value;
var in1 = document.getElementById("photoLink_9795a9ff-f5c2-49b6-bc72-13240caf7a7b_$UrlControlId").value;

var in2 = document.getElementById("nox").value;

localStorage.setItem('myDataKey3', someData);
localStorage.setItem('myDataKey4',in1);

localStorage.setItem("in2", "");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Role_f375d881-c1f7-4171-85d4-a9eb7f6420dd_$TextField">
<input type="text" id="photoLink_9795a9ff-f5c2-49b6-bc72-13240caf7a7b_$UrlControlId">
<input type="text" id="nox" >
<input type=”text” id=”userName” >
```

Comment: you can use the input event listener and update the local storage when the input changes

Comment: is there a reason you are getting the value of `photoLink_...` twice and storing it in two variables?

Answer (score 1):

Autosave should be pretty simple to implement.

All you need to do is use window.setTimeout() once your user edits something that should be autosaved, and have that timeout call the javascript frameworks standard AJAX stuff.

This article might help you:
https://chevtek.io/how-to-implement-autosave-in-your-web-app/